# show checkbox data mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, show

I am having some minor errors and was wondering if anyone could help!

I am creating a attendance system for a college.

**This Scenario:**

Student logs in successfully and then wants to view his/her attendance for a particular course.

**Problem**: I want it to show me both checked and uncheked data from mysql, it currently shows an empty checkbox (when its meant to be checked) also at the moment it is showing numerous duplicated data, is it possible i could limit that, say for example show one record per week , it shows all data and duplicates it.

```
<?php

$q3= "SELECT attendance.week_number_id, attendance.week_number, courses.course_id, students.student_id, course_attendance.present, course_attendance.notes
 FROM courses, course_attendance, attendance, students
WHERE course_attendance.student_id= ".$_SESSION['student_id']." AND course_attendance.course_id= courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id= attendance.week_number_id AND courses.course_id='101'  
 ";


$result = mysql_query($q3)  or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1' align='center'><tr>  <th><strong>Week Number</strong></th> <th><strong>Present</strong></th> <th><strong>Notes</strong></th>  </tr> ";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
echo 

"</td><td  width='200' align='center'>" .$row['week_number'].
"</td><td  width='400' align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='present'" .$row['present']. 
"</td><td  width='400' align='center'>" .$row['notes'].
"</td><tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Note: I am connected successfully to database, mysql is up and running, i am using sessions, currently it does show data for the student but does not show the existing checked or uncheked value, the checkbox is empty.

Can anyone help

Comment: Where is the $checked variable defined?

Comment: sorry its not defined, its $row['present'] , the 'present' field in mySql is a int and defines 1 for being present and 0 for being absent, I want it to show all data whether its 1 or 0 but in a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're not properly defining the checkbox to be checked. Make a code that adds `checked="true"` if the 'present' field is 1.

```
<?php

    $q3 = " SELECT attendance.week_number_id, attendance.week_number, courses.course_id, students.student_id, course_attendance.present, course_attendance.notes 
            FROM courses, course_attendance, attendance, students
            WHERE course_attendance.student_id= ".$_SESSION['student_id']." AND course_attendance.course_id= courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id= attendance.week_number_id AND courses.course_id='101'";


    $result = mysql_query($q3) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "
        <table border='1' align='center'>
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Week Number</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Present</strong></th> 
                <th><strong>Notes</strong></th>  
            </tr>
        ";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $checked = '';
        if($row['present'] == 1) {
            $checked = ' checked="true"';
        }

        echo "
            <tr>
                <td width='200' align='center'>" . $row['week_number'] . "</td>
                <td width='400' align='center'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='present'" .$checked . "/>
                </td>
                <td width='400' align='center'>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }

    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: I am going to try this code now thank u will let u know if it works

Comment: Wow thank you ever so much , it works ! , shows both checked and uncheked value, however now the problem is that it displays duplicated data any way of just showing one data per week

Comment: What do you mean duplicate data? Is there a way I can see this page live?

Comment: For instance Week Number:1  Present:1 Notes:Student was in , Week Number:2 Present:0 Notes:Student Absent.  so it shows the data , but it then repeates the data numerous times

Comment: I neatened code and fixed HTML errors. Don't think I fixed anything else, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
echo 
    "</td><td  width='200' align='center'>" .$row['week_number'].
    "</td><td  width='400' align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='present'" .$row['present']. 
    "</td><td  width='400' align='center'>" .$row['notes'].
    "</td><tr>";
```

statement should be

```
$present = "";
if(.$row['present']==1)
{
   $present = "checked =checked/>";    
}
else
{
   $present = "/>";    
 }
```

echo 
            "" .$row['week_number'].
            "" .$row['notes'].
            "";

Hope this helps you. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using more lines, why not just make a small chunk of code that decides when to add checked="checked" to it with only one block of the HTML code?

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this now

Answer (score 0):

```
$checked = '';
if($present == 1) {
    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
}

echo "</td><td  width='200' align='center'>" .$row['week_number'].
"</td><td  width='400' align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='present'" .$checked . "/>" . 
"</td><td  width='400' align='center'>" .$row['notes'].
"</td><tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Try.